# Why do we say "your letters" and not "the letters"?

Tags: grammar

So I was reading "A Game of Thrones" by George Martin and at one point one of the characters asked another: "Do you know your letters?" meaning "Can you read/write?". So I was wondering why does she said "your letters" not "the letters". I thought that the word "my" describes something that you own like "my car" or "my hand". And nobody owns letters, they just exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To *know one's letters* sounds a bit antiquated/dialectal to me, but the basic form is perfectly natural in usages such as...

> [*"I know my seven times table"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22know%20my%20seven%20times%20table%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)
>    [*"The commentator certainly knows his football"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22know%20my%20seven%20times%20table%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22knows%20his%20football%22&tbm=bks)
>    [*"He's learned his lesson"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22know%20my%20seven%20times%20table%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22he%27s%20learned%20his%20lesson%22&tbm=bks)

I think the idiomatic use of a possessive in such forms reflects either or both of...

> 1: The subject matter was ***assigned to*** the person to be learned (whether he *actually* learned it or not)
>    2: (If they learned it) the knowledge was ***acquired by*** the person, so they now "own" it

Answer (score 1):

The same expression is used for different kind of knowledge, for example:

- Do you know your history?
- Do you know your Byron?

This refers to the persons knowledge in the area, not the knowledge limited to the persons involvment in the area. To know ones history is to have knowledge about history in general, not to know what happened to oneself.

Comment: I must say *"Do you know your history?"* isn't a particularly good example here. You've provided your own "definition", because that was what you had in mind when you wrote it. But it's entirely a matter of *context* whether those exact words refer to *history in general*, or *your **personal** history*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Naturally the example could take a different meaning in a specific context, but that goes for any example, including yours.

Comment: I can't easily think of even a highly-contrived context where the first two of my examples could "literally" mean ***my** seven times table*, or ***his** football*. I did um and ah a bit before adding *learned **his** lesson*, but the "figurative possession" sense there is so idiomatically standard I went with it anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It isnt a matter of how contrived the context would, be but that you need to supply a specific context for the example to have a different meaning.

Comment: But I *did* supply links to numerous written instances of each usage I listed - not that I examined every link, obviously, but it wouldn't be easy to find any there which aren't the "idiomatic, non-possessive" sense. Whereas the first couple of hits for [*Do you know your history*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Do+you+know+your+history%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) are quite obviously referring to the *personal* history of the person being addressed (or that of his own particular social group).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: What are you arguing about really? I'm not trying to "provide my own definition", I don't understand where you get that from. Please stop trying to tell me what I am trying to do, when you obviosuly have no idea.

Comment: I'm not "arguing" (I don't think). I just pointed out that your specific example would only have the relevant meaning *if the context made it clear*. And although it's true you specified *afterwards* what meaning you intended, I can easily imagine that since OP clearly *doesn't* understand the usage he's asking about, he might quite reasonably have asked *"How would I be supposed to infer that meaning?"*. Or worse, he might assume *"Do you know your history?"* always means "history as a general subject", which would be completely wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's maybe what you intended to do, but you didn't.